# Filter datagridview's rows using first row

Tags: c#

I want to create a datagridview and set first row to be filter for each column. Example: Under header i need to have an editable cell. And each time i will press something in this cell to refresh datagridview with items which are like my text-value. I searched in web i didn't found anything.

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("a");
        dt1.Columns.Add("b");

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            dt1.Rows.Add("a" + j.ToString(), "b" + j.ToString());
        }

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;

        //I take a TextBox for example
        TextBox tx = new TextBox();

        //Add this TextBox into the DataGridView's control collection
        this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(tx);

        //Add an extra row into the data source
        dt1.Rows.InsertAt(dt1.NewRow(), 0);

        //Make the first row frozen.
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Frozen = true;

        //Resize the TextBox and put it over the first row
        Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 0, true);
        tx.Location = rect.Location;

        int w = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            w += c.Width;
        }

        tx.Width = w;
        tx.Height = this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height;
    }
}
```